# Why my img tag doesn't work (ruby on rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using ruby on rails. This should be very simple, but it doesn't work. I put my image to assets/images and named it aa2.png. I used in in the view template and it doesn't work. I can't figure out why... Here's the html code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6"><img src="aa2.png"></div>
     <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it must be

```
<img src="/assets/aa2.png">
```

but prefer

```
<%= image_tag("/assets/aa2.png", alt: "logo") %>
```

use browser console to detect file path issues

Comment: don't include `assets` part, just name of file

Answer (score 4):

Use the Image Tag helper

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-6"><%= image_tag('aa2.png') %></div>
     <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using img src, we have use absolute path of the image as:

```
<img src="/assets/aa2.png"/>
```

Comment: This won't work in production when assets have the digest added to them.